# Charge distribution over a finite plate

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Let's say we have a tube(simply a cylinder with no top or bottom) with charge $q_1$, radius $r_1$ and length $l_1$ made out of insulating material. There is also a finite conducting plate with sides' lengths a and b and charge $q_2$. The tube is placed to make its low bottom part face towards the plate like in this figure:

[image]

I mean the electric field between the cylinder and the plate is along the surface of the tube. Thus the question is how would be the charge distribution over the surface of the plate? Would it be like a ring of charges?

P.S: The tube is not bigger than the plate in size. In addition, $q_1$ and $q_2$ have opposite signs.

Comment: Sounds almost like a problem that requires a finite element solver... but maybe, if you are lucky, somebody can still come up with a closed form solution for this one.

Comment: @CuriousOne Not as an answer to that question but can you at least tell me when calculating the electrostatic force between these objects how accurate would my solution be if I took plate as a disc of charges since most of the charges would accumulate like a disc and neglecting other charges which are scattered over the surface of the plate.

Comment: I am afraid, that I couldn't give good estimates for that, either. What is the importance of this problem for you? Do you have an actual application where this plays a role? For practical applications the better way to proceed, in my opinion, is to build a model and to actually measure the forces that you are interested in. With electrostatics the devil is in details that are not captured realistically by theoretical calculations. One big issue here may be the boundary conditions (one can't build anything where "infinity" is really far away) and corona discharge on sharp corners.

Comment: @CuriousOne No I won't make a practical application of it. I am just trying to calculate the force between the plate and tube but I don't know which shape should I take plate as since charges move

Comment: Why would the charge form a disc? I could understand why you might think it were a ring. Also, do $q_1$ and $q_2$ have opposite signs...?

Comment: @RobJeffries I'm sorry I meant ring of charges. And yes they have opposite signs.